# Implement pictures to go along with random quotes?

Tags: android, image

I created a simple android app and have a very simple background image and button. When you press the button one random quote out of 40 that is in a random generator array appears in a textview. Does anyone know how I could code it so there is 40 images to go along with it instead of just one?

Comment: use counter when click on button

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. place 40 pictures in your drawable
2. create a String array of lenght 40 containing the quotes
3. create a int array of same lenght containing the drawable id of the picture. Hence place the id at the same index of the related quote.
4. generate a random number say n, then show the quote[n] as the quote and set the drawable image[n] as the image

Comment: Thanks worked a charm, much appreciated StinePike thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        count++;
        count%=40;
        int res=getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+count,  "drawable",getPackageName());
        image.setBackgroundResource(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: you should explain something about what your code is doing